# Python Cipher Text

Tags: python, encryption

```
def EncryptionString (plaintext, lookup=[]):

    for x in range(0, len(plaintext)):
        outstring = ""
        oldchar = chr(x)
        oldcharvalue = ord(oldchar)
        newchar = lookup[oldcharvalue]
        outstring = outstring + newchar
        return outstring

if __name__ == "__main__":

    Ascii_Look_Up = []
    for i in range(65, 90):
        result = chr((i + 24 - 65) % 26 + 65)
        Ascii_Look_Up.append(result)

Text = "C"

print(EncryptionString(Text, Ascii_Look_Up))
```

please help as the function is giving only encrypt a single letter loop only iterates once further more i have been asked to solve problem by using arrays waiting for you community

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please check [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). what is your question?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, please do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

It encrypts only one letter because your for loop is going to be executed len(text) times and it will be only 1 time because `text = "C"` and `len(text) = 1`

Comment: The return statement is indented too much: it should be executed after the loop, not inside the loop where it returns a value after the first iteration. Your answer is technically correct, but probably not what OP was looking for.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is a lot of problems with this code I think.
For example, if lookup will be empty [] as the default value without entered value suggests then it will return an error on lookup[oldcharvalue]